# Golang: How to color fmt.Fprintf output?

Tags: go

I know I can add colors to fmt.Println output with something like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    colorReset := "\033[0m"
    colorRed := "\033[31m"
    fmt.Println(string(colorRed), "test", string(colorReset))
    fmt.Println("next")
}
```

Is there any way to colorize the output of `fmt.Fprintf`?

Comment: Sure, as long as the program that renders the `w`'s content written by `Fprintf(w ...)` can interpret some color codes, then why not. Just like your terminal understands `"\033[31m"` etc. Just add the correct color codes, whatever they may be, and you're done.

Comment: Yea I'm trying to do that in a web browser for an HTTP server and the color codes don't work there. I was looking for a way to avoid being forced to learn CSS just so my users are not blinded by black text on a white background... I may just have to learn CSS, but I was curious if there was a simple alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the same way you used the Println you can use colors with Fprintf, ex

```golang
const colorRed = "\033[0;31m"
const colorNone = "\033[0m"

func main() {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Red: \033[0;31m %s None: \033[0m %s", "red string", "colorless string")
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Red: %s %s None: %s %s", colorRed, "red string", colorNone, "colorless string")
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works great in a terminal.  Unfourtunately I was hoping to use this in a browser window and it doesn't work there :( Instead it shows up as: `Red: [0;31m red string None: [0m colorless string`. I guess I may need to learn css.

Comment: I found a solution using "html/template" that solves the issue, letting me insert vars directly into HTML with the body `<body bgcolor="black" text="white">`

Answer (score 0):

There was a color package published in November 2023 that makes this pretty easy and expandable with a lot of cool options:

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fatih/color

For example:

```
c := color.New(color.FgCyan)
c.Println("Prints cyan text")
```

Or

```
blue := color.New(color.FgBlue)
blue.Fprint(myWriter, "This will print text in blue.")
```